# MongoDB extend primary key up to 20 bytes

Tags: mongodb, primary-key, extend

MongoDB autogenerates a 12bytes BSON-format _id in order to be used as the primary key of the document, in case that this field is not provided upon insertion.
My question is: 
-1 can I configure MongoDB to generate 20bytes for the primary key? 
-2 If not, can i "force" MongoDB to store 20bytes primary keys, by explicitly assign new documents with their 20bytes keys?
-3, in case of -2, will this stand or MongoDB will throw an excepion?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the format of the built in ObjectId which is what mongoDb uses by default for _id. For questions 2 and 3, you can however assign your own at insertion time. MongoDB will not throw an exception. It does have to be unique, have a unique index on it and cannot be an array. From the documentation:

> The _id field has the following behavior and constraints:
>
> ```
> By default, MongoDB creates a unique index on the _id field during the creation of a collection.
>
> The _id field is always the first field in the documents. If the server receives a document that does not have the _id field first,
> ```
>
> then the server will move the field to the beginning.
>
> ```
> The _id field may contain values of any BSON data type, other than an array.
>
> Warning
>
> To ensure functioning replication, do not store values that are of the BSON regular expression type in the _id field.
> ```
>
> The following are common options for storing values for _id:
>
> - Use an ObjectId.
> - Use a natural unique identifier, if available. This saves space and      avoids an additional index.
> - Generate an auto-incrementing number. See Create an Auto-Incrementing    Sequence Field.
> - Generate a UUID in your application code. For a more efficient       storage of the UUID values in the collection and in the _id index,
>     store the UUID as a value of the BSON BinData type.
>
>   Index keys that are of the BinData type are more efficiently stored in the index if:
>         the binary subtype value is in the range of 0-7 or 128-135, and
>         the length of the byte array is: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 20, 24, or 32.
>
>   Use your driver’s BSON UUID facility to generate UUIDs. Be aware that driver implementations may implement UUID serialization and
>     deserialization logic differently, which may not be fully compatible
>     with other drivers. See your driver documentation for information
>     concerning UUID interoperability.
>
> Note
>
> Most MongoDB driver clients will include the _id field and generate an
>   ObjectId before sending the insert operation to MongoDB; however, if
>   the client sends a document without an _id field, the mongod will add
>   the _id field and generate the ObjectId.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/

Comment: This really helped, as I'm trying to store a 32 array of bytes for the _id. However this article mentions that "the binary subtype value is in the range of 0-7 or 128-135". What does this subtype value actually means?

Comment: You can find some documentation on the subtypes in various mongodb drivers documentation for the bson type - here's the one for python: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/binary.html . Should be the same for all drivers.